# Depth first search and binary tree traversal

Tags: algorithm

Strictly speaking, binary tree pre-order traversal is the same as binary tree depth first search. Binary tree in-order and post-order traversals are not the same as binary tree depth first search. Am I right?

Comment: Nope. Depth-first means the node itself is processed *after* the children, so that is a *post-order traversal*.

Answer (score 0):

All three tree traversals are produced by a depth first search. Whether the current node is added to the output before, after, or between its children doesn't make a difference - the algorithms walk the nodes of the tree in exactly the same order.

Comment: The link below says that depth first search is closely related to preorder traversal: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960215.html

Comment: Well it's not wrong: dfs enters the nodes in pre-order. It exits them in post-order.